# Remove the empty page before a table

Tags: tables, page-breaking, landscape

I have the following problm. My thesis has a landscape oriented table with \scriptsize as size of font. The problem is that I have an empty page before that I can't remove it. If I change the font size to \tiny, I don't have the empty page but the letters are really tiny. Any solution to remove the empty page?

This is part of the code:

```
%First page     
Table summarizes the above mentioned characteristics of the ......

\vfill
%empty page that has to be removed
%Third page
\newpage

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[H]
\scriptsize
\centering
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `\vfill` and `\newpage`? `\vfill` adds vertical space so that whatever comes after it is placed bottom-aligned and `\newpage` does exactly that, start a new page. Also, please provide a full MWE with `\begin{document} … \end{document}`, document class and so on.

Comment: I use \vfill to remove the blank space of the page with the phrase "Table summarizes...". Unfortunately without it the vertical alignment of my page is not good. new page to be sure that I will have the table in a new page and then the table.

Comment: Instead of "\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}" try with the tag "\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}" which comes with the "rotating" package, if it doesn't meet your requirement, then please post the MWE...

Comment: `\begin{landscape}` already forced a pagebreak so `\newpage` isn't doing anything, the `\vfill` also should not be doing anything before a forced page break, but without any usable example it is very hard to guess why you get a blank page. Do you get warnings about overfull boxes?

Comment: Thanks a lot  MadyYuvi. It works.....Perfect....So simple...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would you like to post an answer or should we close as _solved in comments_?

Comment: it's @MadyYuvi could post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "`\begin{landscape}...\end{landscape}`" try with the tag "`\begin{sidewaystable}...\end{sidewaystable}`" which comes with the "`rotating`" package which can help you to fix the issue